# Representation of a positive integer $k$ in term of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, representation-theory

My question is how one can represent a positive integer $k$ in term of complex numbers by using a particular functional equation.

My **attempt**:

The complex logarithm of $(-1)^{k}$ where $k$ is a positive integer is given by

$$log(-1)^{k}=ikπ+2πim$$ for all $m∈ℤ$

Now consider a functional equation of the form:
$$f(s)=(-1)^{k} f(3-s)$$

Let $A$ be the set of complex numbers $s$ such that $f(s)≠0$ then we can represent $k$ as follow:

$$k=1/(iπ)×log(f(s)/f(3-s))-2m$$ for all $m∈ℤ$ and all $s∈A$                      .
Now, I want to remove the positive integer $m$ but I am not able to justify this operation.

Comment: Why should you be able to remove $m$? There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @DonThousand: It is for simplicity and I am looking for one solution.

Comment: Then just plug in a nice value for $m$ and call it a day.

Comment: what has $k$ to do with $f$ and/or the functional equation? If you understand that, you may get your answer

Comment: @Conrad: This is just a representation. You can take any function verifying that functional equation.

Comment: yes, but what is $k$?

Comment: @Conrad: $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: whatever, to me your problem just doesn't make any sense unless more context is provided; since basically $(-1)^k$ has period 2 on integers you just usually have $k=0$ or $k=1$ in such functional equations and using a different one makes sense only if it has some relation with $f$ (in modular forms for example)

Comment: @Conrad: Can you elaborate with the idea related to modular forms.

Comment: I would look in the Iwaniec-Kowalski ANT bible especially in 5.12 where the sign of the functional equation for L functions coming from automorphic forms is defined in terms of the signs at ramified primes - this is an area only tangential to my interests so I know about stuff that appears there, but I am not really competent to explain it